# python でクラスオブジェクトは取得できるか？

Tags: ruby, python

ある程度 ruby を触ったことがあって、 python を触り始めようとしているものです。

python コマンドを起動して、インタラクティブに試行錯誤していると、今保持している object のクラスが何であるか知りたくなりました。(文字列化したときに、 `__str__`で、大体中身が何であるかはわかるようですが、嘘をつかれているかもしれないので、、)

- python において、オブジェクトのクラス(オブジェクト)を取得する方法はありますか？(ruby における、 `.class` メソッドのようなものを想定)

Comment: [introspection - Getting the class name of an instance in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type()` を使うのが一般的ですが、 `obj.__class__` でも取得出来ます。

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> obj = 'hello'
>>> type(obj)
<class 'str'>
>>> obj.__class__
<class 'str'>
```

マニュアル的にはこのへんです。

- http://docs.python.jp/3.5/library/functions.html#type
- http://docs.python.jp/3.5/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: 名前まで取得するなら`obj.__class__.__name__`でいけますね。